# Print character by character of a string

Tags: c, string

The below code  prints characters till 20th, I want the code to print an error if the string size is more than 20.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
   { 
    int i = 0, l = 0;
    char s[20];
    fgets(s, 30, stdin);
    l = strlen(s);
    if (l < 20)
    {
     for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
     printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    }
    }
    else
    printf("Length of the String exceeds the limit.");
    }
```

Comment: `void main()` is wrong, no matter how creative you get in formatting your code...

Comment: `char s[20]; fgets(s,30,stdin);`<- begging for crashes/exploits? This is a *buffer overflow*

Comment: The size of your buffer is 20 and you wonder why it works only up to the 20th char. What could be wrong here??

Comment: You cannot measure whether your jug has more than 5 liters of beer by using a beer glass of a pint size at one shot...can you?

Comment: @FelixPalmen `void main()` is not certainly wrong.  C specifies that `main()` may have other implementation defined signatures.  See C11 5.1.2.2.1 1. IAC, that issue is not central to OP's issue.

Comment: Avoid size issues, Instead of `fgets(s, 30, stdin);`, use `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);` for consistent code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains undefined behaviour if someone enters more that 19 characters. This is because `char s[20]` reserves 20 characters (including string termination character `'\0'`). So reading in more than 20 characters using `fgets(s,30,stdin)` may lead to almost anything, including entering the "wrong" path in the remainder of the program.

Try `char s[30]` and test your code again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It had worked. I'm very new to coding and would love to learn, I have to complete the learning course but I'm getting many errors while writing programs. Is there any way I can become good at coding?

Comment: @AkshayKumarAkkinapelli no offense intended, but *apply logic*. See the comment of SouravGhosh on your question for an example.

Comment: Thanks @FelixPalmen, It's okay, I want to learn and I know that, to learn you need to let go of the ego. I'm at level-1 at coding I guess and need a mentor/ a guide to help me.